# ionic 4 ion-slider lock at the last slide

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm developing an ionic 4 mobile app with an ion-slider that slides horizontally. the slider is working. but I couldn't stop the sliding at the last slide. I need to lock my last slide at the slider.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 100%">

    <ion-slides [options]="sliderConfig" style="width: 100%" #slides>

        <ion-slide style=" margin-left: -30%">
            <div style="float:left">
                <!-- <ion-card style="width: 180px; height: 200px;" >
                                <ion-card-content> -->
                <ion-avatar style="height: 110px;width: 110px" align="center">
                    <img src="../../../assets/f1.jpg" style="width: 100%; height:100%" />

                </ion-avatar>
                <!-- <img src="../../../assets/food.jpg" style="width:220px; height:200px"/>   -->

                <ion-label>
                    Promo
                </ion-label>
                <!-- </ion-card-content>
                            </ion-card> 
          -->
            </div>

        </ion-slide>

        <ion-slide style="margin-left: -20%">
            <div style="float:left">
                <ion-avatar style="height: 110px;width: 110px" align="center">
                    <img src="../../../assets/food.jpg" style="width: 100%; height:100%" />

                </ion-avatar>
                <ion-label>
                    New
                </ion-label>
            </div>

        </ion-slide>

        <ion-slide style="width:100%; margin-left: -20%">
            <div style="float:left">
                <ion-avatar style="height: 110px;width: 110px" align="center">
                    <img src="../../../assets/sri.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%" />

                </ion-avatar>
                <ion-label>
                    Sri Lankan
                </ion-label>
            </div>

        </ion-slide>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code. I did some modification.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 100%">

<ion-slides style="width: 100%" #slides>

    <ion-slide>
      <ion-card style="width: 180px; height: 200px;" >
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-avatar style="height: 110px;width: 110px" align="center">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjavZyClMXiAhVFVH0KHcbcAu4QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pexels.com%2Fsearch%2Fnature%2F&psig=AOvVaw3lI4NtiR2SsIzSprapcqzp&ust=1559371058163196" style="width: 100%; height:100%" />

            </ion-avatar>

            <ion-label>
                Promo
            </ion-label>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card> 

    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>
      <ion-card style="width: 180px; height: 200px;" >
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-avatar style="height: 110px;width: 110px" align="center">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjavZyClMXiAhVFVH0KHcbcAu4QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pexels.com%2Fsearch%2Fnature%2F&psig=AOvVaw3lI4NtiR2SsIzSprapcqzp&ust=1559371058163196" style="width: 100%; height:100%" />

            </ion-avatar>

            <ion-label>
                Promo
            </ion-label>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card> 

    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>
      <ion-card style="width: 180px; height: 200px;" >
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-avatar style="height: 110px;width: 110px" align="center">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjavZyClMXiAhVFVH0KHcbcAu4QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pexels.com%2Fsearch%2Fnature%2F&psig=AOvVaw3lI4NtiR2SsIzSprapcqzp&ust=1559371058163196" style="width: 100%; height:100%" />

            </ion-avatar>

            <ion-label>
                Promo
            </ion-label>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card> 

    </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

App Url = [enter link description here](https://ionic-fbfhzs.stackblitz.io/)

editor Url  = [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fbfhzs)

**You have used margin left 25%. that is the issue i think**

Comment: yeah its worked!! Thank you so much !! the problem is with my margin-left. thanks again